# C++11 class that can only be implicitly constructed?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to make a type that has zero size and can only be constructed implicitly?

The use case is to prevent some public members of a struct from being initialized via the brace syntax:

```
class Barrier { ... };


struct Foo {
  int user_sets;
  int* this_to;

  Barrier _bar;

  int *must_be_zero_init_by_linker;
};

Foo foo = {1};               // ok
Foo bar = {1, nullptr};      // ok
Foo baz = {1, nullptr, {}};  // must error
```

---

Edit: one other constraint: The Foo object must be linker initialized so it can't define constructors or private members.

Comment: Does `class Barrier { Barrier() { } };` not work?

Comment: I'm not sure what "can only be implicitly constructed" means. Do you want an error for `Barrier()`? That does rather explicitly construct a `Barrier` object.

Comment: Zero size? Do you mean a type `T` such that `sizeof(T) == 0`? That cannot happen according to the rules of C++.

Comment: @Mehrdad   struct   Barrier { Barrier() { } }; works fine for me.

Comment: @Mehrdad I think that can't be implicitly constructed either.

Answer (score 5):

You could define your own constructor; this prevents your class from being an aggregate. For example:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo(int a = 0, int * p = nullptr) constexpr
  : user_sets(a), this_to(p), must_be(nullptr)
  {}

  int user_sets;
  int* this_to;

  int *must_be;
};

Foo foo = { 1 };                 // ok
Foo bar = { 1, nullptr };        // ok
// Foo baz = { 1, nullptr, {} }; // error
```

In fact, I would recommend making the constructor `explicit` - then you can't use copy-initialization, but you can still use list-initialization:

```
explicit Foo(int a = 0, int * p = nullptr) constexpr /* ... */

Foo foo { 1 };                   // ok
Foo bar { 1, nullptr };          // ok
// Foo baz { 1, nullptr, {} };   // error
```

Comment: This is a much more idiomatic way to solve the problem.

Comment: explicit constructors are run at run-time, it needs to be at link time. That is the object needs to be valid at the point the main thread starts running.

Comment: No, the explicit constructor keyword prevents implicit construction at compile time. See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/121163/850326

Comment: @BCS: You can also make the constructor `constexpr` to make it eligible for the use in constant expressions. I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an explicit default constructor will work:

```
struct Barrier { explicit constexpr Barrier() {} };
```

That gives the behaviour you want:

```
Foo foo = {1};               // ok
Foo bar = {1, nullptr};      // ok
Foo baz = {1, nullptr, {}};  // error
```

Note that the behaviour might change depending on the eventual resolution of [DR 1518](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1518), so KerrekSB's answer is more reliable and less subtle.